# ElasticSearch - create template to match entity by an entity name pattern?

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say I have this template

```
{
    "template" : "te*",
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "type1" : {
            properties":{"TemplateField":{"enabled": false },.... }
        }
    }
}
```

It matches indices that match the pattern te*.

I want inside the indice to match only entity type that there name is eqaul to TypeA, TypeB, TypeF

something that will look like

```
{
    "template" : "te*",
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "typeA, TypeB, TypeC" : {
              properties":{"TemplateField":{"enabled": false },.... }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would look like this:

```
{
    "template" : "te*",
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "typeA" : {
            "properties":{"TemplateField":{"enabled": false } }
        },
        "TypeB" : {
            "properties":{"TemplateField":{"enabled": false } }
        },
        "TypeC" : {
            "properties":{"TemplateField":{"enabled": false } }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to repeat the template (if I have several fields in the properties)?

Comment: For the portion shared by all types in the index you can use [default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/default-mapping.html) mapping, otherwise the only way to repeat the type is by having a loop in the application that generate the template (your client application). There is no macro expansion or type inheritance mechanism built into elasticsearch. By the way, please check out https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring before you invest too heavily into complex type structure.

Comment: Thanks. btw: It says "we only enforce the new rules when creating new indices in Elasticsearch v2.0". ES is currently v1.7.1. What does it mean?

Comment: It means that some indices created in 1.7.1 can have settings that are no longer valid in 2.0 and still be migrated to 2.0.0. However, you will not be able to recreate indices with such settings in 2.0.0.